# memcpy vtkPoints using GetVoidPointer method

Tags: c++, opencv, vtk

I have a opencv 3-channel Mat which each pixel contains a 3D point.
Now I want to copy this Mat (points) to VTK points and then polydata to visualize it.
There is an example [here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/ColoredPoints) showing this but I want to copy the cv::Mat to vtkPoints directly using memcpy.

I did:

```
// Create colored point clodu in opencv format
cv::Mat cld_cv = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 3, CV_32FC3);
int num_points = cld_cv.cols * cld_cv.rows;

// Fill cld_cv code here
// .....

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();
points->SetNumberOfPoints(num_points);
::memcpy(points->GetVoidPointer(0), cld_cv.data, sizeof(float) * num_points * 3);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> pointsPolydata =
        vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

pointsPolydata->SetPoints(points);

// Normal VTK pipeline as shown in the example
```

However I can only see 1 point which seems to be at origin.
Please point out where I have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

What version of OpenCV are you using? I don't see any `cv::Mat::data` in the currents docs.

Also, there is no guarantee that `vtkPoints` or `cv::Mat` are stored in a contiguous block of memory. Looking at the VTK 6.2 source, the data inside `vtkPoints` is stored as a `FloatArray` by default, which has contiguous storage, so you should be ok there. OpenCV provides a method to check. Try

```
if (cld_cv.isContinuous()) 
   ::memcpy(points->GetVoidPointer(0), cld_cv.ptr<float>(), sizeof(float) * num_points * 3);
else  {
    std::cerr << "cv Mat not contiguous" << std::endl; 
    // other, perhaps not as fast, method of copy
}
```

See the OpenCV [docs for isContinous](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aff83775c7fc1479de5f4a8c4e67fe361) for details.

Comment: `uchar * cv::Mat::data` seems to remain in Cv 3.1.

Comment: I use OpenCV 2.4.11, but as @mainactual said it should also available in OpenCV3. I will test if the Mat in my case is continuous. Thanks